# Spring MVC Data binding error

Tags: spring-mvc

When submitting a form I get the message:

> com.xxx.mvc.reports.ReportController: Data binding errors: 6 {||||||| - |}

The command class inherits from an abstract base class.

When using debugging I can see that the values are set on the command class. I use spring 2.5. Somehwere after the fields are set and between the calling of onSubmit in the controller the error occurs. I use a SimpelFormController. The onSubmit method isn't called so I can't inspect the BindException there.

What does this mean and how can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I barely posted the question and I found the answer:

```
<form:errors path="pathName"/>
```

gives me the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily see every binding error related to your command bean in the page, put something like:

```
<spring:bind path="command.*">
    <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
        <font color="red">Error code: <c:out value="${error}"/></font>
        <br><br>
    </c:forEach>
</spring:bind>
```

The code is for a bean named "command", as default.